# How to compare current row with previous column next row in sql

Tags: sql

```
Date from    Date to    
2018-12-11  2019-01-08   
2019-01-08  2019-02-09  
2019-02-10  2019-03-14  
2019-03-17  2019-04-11   
2019-04-15  2019-05-16  
2019-05-16  2019-06-13
```

output will be like this

```
Date from     Date to     Days
2018-12-11   2019-01-08   0 
2019-01-08   2019-02-09   1
2019-02-10   2019-03-14   3
2019-03-17   2019-04-11   4 
2019-04-15   2019-05-16   0
2019-05-16   2019-06-13   -
```

Comment: Date functions are notably vendor specific. Please tag your question with the RDBMS that you are using: sql-server, oracle, mysql, ...

Answer (score 0):

You want `lead()` and a date diff function:

```
select 
    date_from,
    date_to,
    datediff(day, date_to, lead(date_from) over(order by date_from)) days
from mytable
```

`datediff()` is a SQLServer function. There are equivalents in other RDBMS.

Side note: I would recommend againts using a string value (`-`) for records that do not have a *next* record, since other values are numeric (the datatypes in a column must be consistant). `null` is good enough for this (which the above query will produce).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=15031937587a85d5323e49350dcb6c20)**:

```
date_from           | date_to             | days
:------------------ | :------------------ | ---:
11/12/2018 00:00:00 | 08/01/2019 00:00:00 |    0
08/01/2019 00:00:00 | 09/02/2019 00:00:00 |    1
10/02/2019 00:00:00 | 14/03/2019 00:00:00 |    3
17/03/2019 00:00:00 | 11/04/2019 00:00:00 |    4
15/04/2019 00:00:00 | 16/05/2019 00:00:00 |    0
16/05/2019 00:00:00 | 13/06/2019 00:00:00 | null
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But here it giving only current row difference.I need previous column next row difference

Comment: @Upender: that is what the query does. `lead(date_from) over(order by date_from)` gives you `date_from` in the next row (ordered by `date_from`).

Comment: @Upender: I added a DB Fiddle to my answer for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

To return the difference between two date values in days you could use the DATEDIFF() Function, something like:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, DayFrom, DayTo) AS 'DaysBetween'
FROM DateTable
```

Comment: This is working only for prevoius column value only